# Ubuntu thinks I am in Lisbon, Portugal

Tags: ubuntu, date-time

I installed my first Ubuntu on my laptop last weekend.

Whenever I look at the date it is off by several hours.

My computer thinks I am in Lisbon, Portugal.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you just tried changing the timezone?

Comment: Sorry, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes and upvotes.  If you want help answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press the Windows flag key briefly (=> "Super key" in Ubuntu; between the left side CTRL and ALT on my keyboard)
2. ... and the "Launcher" will open.
3. Type `system set` and the "System Settings" icon should appear, click on it.
4. A window with the title "System settings" should open.
5. At the very bottom you find "Time & Date", click on your country on
   the map
6. if necessary amend by selecting "Manually" below the map, then e.g. type at least three letters of a city name in the box.
7. Close the window when done.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using the command line to set/update your time config, `timedatectl` is your friend. ;-)

List the available settings; Find the correct one for you:

```
timedatectl list-timezones  [--no-pager]
```

Set your desired timezone:

```
timedatectl set-timezone America/Denver
```

`status` will list the current "Time zone"

```
timedatectl status
```

You can also examine `/etc/localtime`

```
ls -l /etc/localtime  
cat /etc/localtime
```